# How to get treeview control of one form in another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a custom control in which there is a

```
treeview with some nodes .
```

I am providing user an option to add new node in the selected node by right click.
For this ,I am opening a Form in which user gives the new name in the text box and press add button , Now if there is no node with the same name then there is a node added into the selected

```
treeview.
```

My problem is that i am not be able to add the node at the runtime with the new name.
I need this

```
treeview
```

in my Form but i am not be able to do this.
I am opening the form from my custom control

```
addInTreeView() method call
```

in which i am opening this form like this :

```
Form_NewForm.ShowDialog();
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont' neccessarily need the treeview in your "new form". If I understand you correct the "new form" is simply shown to the user to enter a name for a new tree node.
Go the other way round: get the entered name from the textbox in your "main form".

Something like this in your mainform that holds the treeview (pseudo-codish):

```
string newNodeName = null;
Form_NewForm.FormClosing += delegate (Object s, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    newNodeName = textBox_newName.Text;
}
Form_NewForm.ShowDialog();

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newNodeName)) {
    //add new node to treeview
}
```

Most likely this concept has to be extended to check if the user cancelled the operation, because you don't want to create a new node if the user clicked "Cancel".

Comment: I am not much familiar with the delegate. Can you please give me some more explanation. @Basti M

Comment: I just added an event handler to handle the `FormClosing`-event. When the "new form" closes it will retrieve the input in the textbox. The delegate is just an anonymous method. Usually you would write something like `Form_NewForm.FormClosing += HandleFormClosing;` together with a method `private void HandleFormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs eventargs)`

Comment: I am not getting this as will this whole code be written into newForm or in the control where the treeview is?

Comment: Citing myself: `... in your mainform that holds the treeview`. Be aware that my code above is kinda pseudo-code. It's more important you understand my concept (of not throwing the treeview into the new form, but to get the text you need out of the new form and leave the rest up to the form holding the treeview).

Comment: Yes i understand but i am not understanding that after closing the newForm how can i get back into the custom form where the treeview is and your last if statement should be writen inside which particular method of the custom form?

Comment: After showDialog(), Method ended its call.. don't mind i am a new user sorry for taking your valuable time ..

Comment: `FormClosing` will be called AFTER `ShowDialog()` returns, as this is just an event. The concept in general: you have Form `A` which holds the treeview and you have Form `B` which holds a textbox to enter a new node name. You open `B` from within `A`, add the `FormClosing` handler to `B` in `A` and add the new node after `B` is closed.

Comment: Please reply if you are here @Basti M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84467/discussion-between-manish-jain-and-basti-m).